# Using react Modal that can be triggered from multiple pages react/next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a Modal that is triggered but many different buttons across different components. I Have been able to get it working on the pages by passing the variables in the Layout, for example

```
    const index = () => {
       const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
       const handleShow = () => { setShow(true) }
       const handleClose = () => { setShow(false) }

       <Layout pageTitle={pageTitle} metaUrl={metaUrl} show={show} onHide={handleHide}>
       ...
       </Layout>
    }
```

And using these variables to pass to the Modal component from the Layout which triggers the modal just fine. But it only works with pages because I can pass them in the layout, however I have buttons in the Navbar and Footer that are being imported into the Layout and not using the Layout so im not sure how to actually pass the variables to the modal from those.

Any Help would be amazing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for this situation, I think the perfect solution would be to use React Context you could separate it in its own hook and then use this hook when needed across the app.
first, you will need to create the context

```js
const ModalContext = React.createContext()
// give it a display name so it would be easier to debug
ModalContext.dispalyName = 'ModalContext'
```

then you need need to create the Provider for this context and put it higher in your app tree because you can only use this context under its Provider since you are using Next.js I would suggest doing it in the _app.js or just around your main app component.

```js
const ModalContextProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [isOpend, setIsOpend] = React.useState(false);
   // handle any additional data needed with useState/useReducer
   const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('default title');

   const value = {setIsOpened, setTitle};

  return <ModalContext.Provider value={value}>
          <ModalComponent isOpend={isOpend} title={title}/>
           {children}
        </ModalContext.Provider>
}
```

so after creating the ModalContext component and putting it above your main app component you can extract this context functionality in its own hook like this

```js
function useModalContext() {
   const context = React.useContext(ModalContext);
   // if context is undefined this means it was used outside of its provider
   // you can throw an error telling that to your fellow developers
   if(!context) {
     throw new Error('useModalContext must be used under <ModalContextProvider/>');
   }
   return context;
}
```

then in any component, you can use this hook like this

```js
const {setIsOpened, setTitle} = useModalContext();

const handleOpenModal() {
  setIsOpened(true);
  setTitle('Modal Title');
}

return <button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Show Modal</button>
```

and you can use this any place in the app if it was under the context provider component.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!